# Why does the text go outside of the box when I resize the browser?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this boxes responsive but as soon as I resize the browser they jump down below the image. What could I do to make this text and image to stay together when I resize the browser? I tried to remove the `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: row;` but then the text goes below the image and not beside it.

```css
.container img {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.container p {
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
}

.container h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #a57354;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wine-row {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: dashed 1.5px #a57354;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

.wine-text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wow zoomIn wine-row">
    <img src="klipp.jpg">
    <div class="wine-text-container">
      <h1> Klippning </H1>
      <p>Påbörjas med en konsulation där du berättar hur du tänker kring resultatet. Därefter fräschar vi upp din frysir utifrån dina önskemål. Vi hjälper dig gärna med tips och råd gällande din hårtyp och styling.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wow zoomIn wine-row">
    <img src="shavee.jpg">
    <div class="wine-text-container">
      <h1> Rakning</H1>
      <p> Vi inleder med en konsulation där kunden ger sina tankar kring ett resultat. Därefter använder vi oss av verktyg och produkter som passar just din skäggutväxt för att åstadkomma ditt val av resultat. Rakning avslutas självklart med ett kalt och
        uppfirskande omslag. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wow zoomIn wine-row">
    <img src="ansikt.jpg">
    <div class="wine-text-container">
      <h1> Ansiktsbehandling </H1>
      <p>Kundens val av ansiktsbehandling. Empire barber erbjuder uppfriskande och avslappnande ansiktsbehandling, behandling som innehåller rengöring, hudanalys och peeling. Ge dig själv eller någon annan vän, familj en present av denna typ av behandling
        som utförs av våra erfarna barberare.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code , this will help you.

```css
.container img {
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.container p {
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
}

.container h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #a57354;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.wine-row {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: dashed 1.5px #a57354;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.wow.zoomIn.wine-row {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wow zoomIn wine-row">
    <img src="klipp.jpg">
    <div class="wine-text-container">
      <h1> Klippning </H1>
      <p>Påbörjas med en konsulation där du berättar hur du tänker kring resultatet. Därefter fräschar vi upp din frysir utifrån dina önskemål. Vi hjälper dig gärna med tips och råd gällande din hårtyp och styling.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wow zoomIn wine-row">
    <img src="shavee.jpg">
    <div class="wine-text-container">
      <h1> Rakning</H1>
      <p> Vi inleder med en konsulation där kunden ger sina tankar kring ett resultat. Därefter använder vi oss av verktyg och produkter som passar just din skäggutväxt för att åstadkomma ditt val av resultat. Rakning avslutas självklart med ett kalt och
        uppfirskande omslag. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wow zoomIn wine-row">
    <img src="ansikt.jpg">
    <div class="wine-text-container">
      <h1> Ansiktsbehandling </H1>
      <p>Kundens val av ansiktsbehandling. Empire barber erbjuder uppfriskande och avslappnande ansiktsbehandling, behandling som innehåller rengöring, hudanalys och peeling. Ge dig själv eller någon annan vän, familj en present av denna typ av behandling
        som utförs av våra erfarna barberare.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want my image to be rounded :D

Comment: Yes you can add this css:   border-radius: 50%;

Answer (score 0):

You should be very clear on what you are expecting as a final output. As you told I have made the image to appeared as round/circled

```css
.container img {
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container p {
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
}

.container h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #a57354;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.wine-row {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: dashed 1.5px #a57354;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.wow.zoomIn.wine-row {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wow zoomIn wine-row">
    <img src="https://99designs-start-attachments.imgix.net/alchemy-pictures/2016%2F02%2F22%2F04%2F24%2F31%2Fb7bd820a-ecc0-4170-8f4e-3db2e73b0f4a%2F550250_artsigma.png?auto=format&ch=Width%2CDPR&w=250&h=250">
    <div class="wine-text-container">
      <h1> Klippning </H1>
      <p>Påbörjas med en konsulation där du berättar hur du tänker kring resultatet. Därefter fräschar vi upp din frysir utifrån dina önskemål. Vi hjälper dig gärna med tips och råd gällande din hårtyp och styling.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wow zoomIn wine-row">
    <img src="https://99designs-start-attachments.imgix.net/alchemy-pictures/2016%2F02%2F22%2F04%2F24%2F31%2Fb7bd820a-ecc0-4170-8f4e-3db2e73b0f4a%2F550250_artsigma.png?auto=format&ch=Width%2CDPR&w=250&h=250">
    <div class="wine-text-container">
      <h1> Rakning</H1>
      <p> Vi inleder med en konsulation där kunden ger sina tankar kring ett resultat. Därefter använder vi oss av verktyg och produkter som passar just din skäggutväxt för att åstadkomma ditt val av resultat. Rakning avslutas självklart med ett kalt och
        uppfirskande omslag. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wow zoomIn wine-row">
    <img src="https://99designs-start-attachments.imgix.net/alchemy-pictures/2016%2F02%2F22%2F04%2F24%2F31%2Fb7bd820a-ecc0-4170-8f4e-3db2e73b0f4a%2F550250_artsigma.png?auto=format&ch=Width%2CDPR&w=250&h=250">
    <div class="wine-text-container">
      <h1> Ansiktsbehandling </H1>
      <p>Kundens val av ansiktsbehandling. Empire barber erbjuder uppfriskande och avslappnande ansiktsbehandling, behandling som innehåller rengöring, hudanalys och peeling. Ge dig själv eller någon annan vän, familj en present av denna typ av behandling
        som utförs av våra erfarna barberare.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```